How do you process all pasted changes in React Ag-Grid at once?
In React Ag-Grid, if a user pastes data into multiple cells at once, the valueSetter gets called for each cell that was pasted. This significantly slows down rendering, because if a user wants to paste into 10 cells, then valueSetter gets called 10 times (the data in my Ag-Grid is managed using redux, so I must dispatch an update when changes occur in Ag-Grid). Ideally, the valueSetter could group all of the changes and then only get called once.
Here is my onChange function:
  const onChange = (params) => {
    const uuid = params.data['UUID'];
    var newValue = params.newValue;
    const field = params.colDef.field;
    const updates = [{tableName: props.tableName, newValues: [newValue], updateColumnNames:[field], uuids:[uuid]}];
    dispatch(updateTableMulti(updates));
  }

The onChange function is associated with each column through the columndDefinition parameter, as
   colDefs.push({'field': colName,
     'headerName': columnHeader,
     ...,
     'valueSetter': (params) => {onChange(params); return true},
                          headerTooltip: headerTooltip,
                          ...type
   }) 

I've tried using the onPasteStart and onPasteEnd parameters of AgGridReact to indicate when onChange should group together updates, but, the onChange function is getting called before onPasteStart even registers.

Well it's not pretty but I did find a way to resolve my own question. The AgGridReact object accepts a parameter processDataFromClipboard, which allows you to build a function that edits the pasted data prior to processing it. I use this function to add some metadata to the pasted values indicating that I should process the pasted data in bulk rather than one at a time.
If anyone has a more graceful answer I would welcome it.
Here are the relevant parts of my code:


const CLIPBOARD_INDICATOR = generateUUID(); // this is used to indicate that the bulk update is in progress
const CLIPBOARD_END_INDICATOR = '_END'; // this is used to indicate that the bulk update is complete

const DataEntryTable = (props) => {

  const DEFAULT_BULK_UPDATE = {tableName: props.tableName, newValues: [], updateColumnNames:[], uuids:[]}
  const [bulkUpdates, setBulkUpdates] = useState(DEFAULT_BULK_UPDATE);

  const onChange = (params) => {
    const uuid = params.data['UUID'];
    var newValue = params.newValue;
    var isBulkUpdate = false;
    var submitBulk = false;
    if (Array.isArray(newValue)) {
      if (newValue.length > 1) {
        if (newValue[newValue.length - 2] == CLIPBOARD_INDICATOR) {
            isBulkUpdate = true;
            if (newValue[newValue.length - 1] == CLIPBOARD_END_INDICATOR) {
            submitBulk = true;
            }
            newValue = newValue[0]
            }  
        }
        }
    }

    if (isBulkUpdate) {
      bulkUpdates['newValues'].push(newValue);
      bulkUpdates['updateColumnNames'].push(field);
      bulkUpdates['uuids'].push(uuid);
      if (submitBulk) {
        dispatch(updateTableMulti(bulkUpdates));
        setBulkUpdates(DEFAULT_BULK_UPDATE);
      }
    } else {
      const updates = {tableName: props.tableName, newValues: [newValue], updateColumnNames:[field], uuids:[uuid]};
      dispatch(updateTableMulti(updates));
    }

  function processDataFromClipboard (params) {
    const clipboardData = params.data;
    // for each entry in params.data, add the clipboard indicator to the end of the array
    clipboardData.forEach((row, row_idx) => {
      row = [row[0], CLIPBOARD_INDICATOR];
      if (row_idx == clipboardData.length - 1) {
        // on the last entry, add the end indicator
        row.push(CLIPBOARD_END_INDICATOR);
      }
    });
    return clipboardData;
  }

  return (
    <AgGridReact
    onChange={(params) => onChange(params)}
    processDataFromClipboard={(params) => processDataFromClipboard(params)}
    {...otherProps}
    />
  )
};



